# Prove $x^5 + x^4 + x^3 + x^2 + 1 = 0$ has no rational solution

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

Prove $x^5 + x^4 + x^3 + x^2 + 1 = 0$ has no rational solution

I want to prove it by Proof by Contradiction, but I am not sure how to proceed with the proof.

Comment: For the benefit of anyone like myself who was confused at first, note the polynomial is missing the $x^1$ term. Otherwise, the roots would just the $6$th roots of unity besides $1$.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

By the [rational root theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_root_theorem) the only possible solutions would be $1$ and $-1$. Evaluate for both and conclude they are not roots.

Comment: That is so simple. I was focused on doing it using contradiction that I missed that. Thank you!

Answer (score 6):

Assume you have a solution $x = \frac{p}{q}$ where $p$ and $q$ are relatively prime (so the fraction is reduced.  Plug $x$ into the equation and then multiply both sides by $q^5$ to clear fractions.  You get an equation that allows you conclude that one of $p$ or $q$ must divide the other, which you assumed was not the case, so you have a contradiction..

Comment: He still needs to check for $1$ and $-1$. since those number do have expressions as a fraction where the numerator and denominator are relatively prime and divide each other.

Comment: That is correct.

Answer (score 4):

I think that Jorge Fernández' solution is the most effective.

So, here we go for an overkill. Since $p(x)$ splits as:
$$ (x^2+x-1)(x^3-x-1)$$
over $\mathbb{F}_3$, it has no rational root.

Comment: what is $\mathbb F_3$?

Comment: Finite field of order $3$.

Comment: I need further explanation.

Comment: @JorgeFernández: Assuming that $p(x)$ has a rational root, then $p(x)$ must decompose over $\mathbb{F}_3$ as a product of irreducible polynomials, and at least one of them must be a linear factor. Since this is not the case (to factor a polynomial over a finite field is an easy task), $p(x)$ has no rational root.